# Office 365 Security and Compliance enabling Safe Attachments

Tags: microsoft-office-365, azure-web-apps

we are looking to enable Safe Documents for Office 365 ProPlus to ensure when protected view is turned off to edit a document, malicious files are not opened.

The problem I have is that there doesn't seem to be a way to pilot this on a few users at first rather than tick it for the whole environment.

[Safe attachment checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKCNY.png)

Can anyone suggest a way I can test it on a small group of users first before rolling it out to everyone?

Thanks.